# Complex Results Filtration with Multiple Criteria in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm, filtering

Please check my sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-mclaren-dhw88 , I couldn't paste all my code here .

I'm making tours filtration with multiple criteria . Each tour is a object

```
{
      id: 4,
      difficulty: "hard",
      is_exclusive: 0,
      duration: 13,
      days: 14,
      image: "5d72500fab232.jpg",
      price: 1300,
      title: "charyn canyon  ",
      slug: "charynskiy-kan-on",
      destinations: [
        {
          id: 2,
          title: "Desert tours"
        }
      ],
      season: "winter"
    },
```

In filter block I'm collecting data by which criteria filter my tours. Here how it looks :

[image]

```
{
 destinations: ["Desert tours"," Nursultan"]
 season: ["summer","winter"]
 difficulty:["hard","normal"]
 price: 3000
 is_exclusive: false
 duration: "one-five"
}
```

After that I'm looping all tours and compare it with my filter object. If any values matches I'm pushing it to an array where it renders. The problem is it pushes all tours where value matches. For example if I picked "desert tours"  and set season to "winter" , it push all tours with "desert tours" and all tours with "winter" season, so result can be "desert tour" with "summer" season. I need to filter it exactly by criteria which user picked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that all applied criteria are satisfied **before** you push the tour item in the array. You can do that in several ways - for example, you could use [every() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

```
tours.forEach(tour => {
    const allCriteriaSatisfied = Object.keys(filterOptions).every(optionName => {
        const optionValue = filterOptions[optionName]

        // if an option is not set, return true
        if (!optionValue) return true;

        // insert code here for each specific criterion
        // and return true if a criterion is satisfied

        // end with return false statement
        return false;
    })
    if (allCriteriaSatisfied) toursArray.push(tour);
})
```

On a side note, instead of using a keyword for each of the duration cases ("less-one", "one-five"...), a better way to encode your duration filter would be to use minDuration and maxDuration variables. That way you wouldn't have to check each of the cases explicitly, but rather do it only once:

```
  let isDurationFilterSatisfied = true
  if (minDuration && tour.days < minDuration) { 
     isDurationFilterSatisfied = false
  }
  if (maxDuration && tour.days > maxDuration) {
     isDurationFilterSatisfied = false
  }
  return isDurationFilterSatisfied
```